# Overcome Windows 7 shell MAX_PATH limit

Tags: shell, windows-7, max-path, short-filenames

If context menu key that launches some executable exists in Windows registry and the `"%1"` command line patrameter place holder is mentioned, the path this executable gets over `GetCommandLine()` is  limited to `MAX_PATH` and in some cases Windows tries to make the short path name out of it.

Example:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\showpath\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Utilities\\COMLINE.EXE\" \"%1\""
```

When the path is:

```
"\\\\SERVER\MediaFilder25\Philosophic\20220407 Draft thoughts. Questions without answers on the background of the torn Internet\20220407-1 Draft thoughts. Questions without answers on the background of the torn Internet\20220407 Draft thoughts. Questions without answers on the background of the torn Internet.ysssss"
```

COMLINE.EXE will get following:

```
"\\\\SERVER\MediaFilder25\39FC~1\202204~3\202204~2\20220407 Draft thoughts. Questions without answers on the background of the torn Internet.ysssss"
```

Nowadays `string` length isn't limited. NTFS path depth isn't limited, too.

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way in registry to allow long paths, explained in [this URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd).

I comes down to the following registry key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]
"LongPathsEnabled"=dword:00000001
```

In order to know your current value, you might do this:

```
reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" | findstr "LongPathsEnabled"
```

It is limited to Windows 10, Version 1607, and Later, but your question is about Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10, Version 1607 contains `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll`.

There is a replica version of `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll` that can manipulate long paths the way the Windows 10, Version 1607 it does.

Source code is available here: https://github.com/nalexandru/api-ms-win-core-path-HACK

I managed to compile it in Visual Studio 2012 after switching platform toolset to v110 and tested it successfully, for example, with Python 3.9 that relies now on this DLL.

I think, Windows 7 shell can't take advantage of using `LongPathsEnabled` registry parameter out of the box, and applications should use this DLL directly (but in this case - why to use a DLL? we can build the proper function right into the application). My question was whether the shell can take advantage of it, and the answer is - "not yet!". It depends on shell itself.